# attach ActiveX into win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, ocx

i create win32 application and i want to attach an ActiveX into so i proceed like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exdisp.h>



#using <System.dll>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

// Constants

namespace {
   TCHAR * windowClassName = TEXT("win32host");
   TCHAR * windowTitle     = TEXT("Win32 interface");
   int          windowWidth     = 600;
   int          windowHeight    = 600;
}

    HWND container;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT messg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
switch(messg)
{
case WM_SIZE:
// Redimensionnement du conteneur quand la taille de la fenêtre change:
MoveWindow(container,0,0,LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam),1);
break;
case WM_CLOSE:
// Détruire la fenêtre principale:
DestroyWindow(hWnd);
break;
case WM_DESTROY:
// Envoyer le message de sortie du programme:
PostQuitMessage( 0 );
break;
default:
//Retour:
return( DefWindowProc( hWnd, messg, wParam, lParam ) );
}
return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
   HINSTANCE hInstance,
   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
   int nCmdShow)
{

   // Register our Window class
   WNDCLASS wndclass;
   wndclass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
   wndclass.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc;
   wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
   wndclass.hIcon = NULL;
   wndclass.hCursor = NULL;
   wndclass.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast <HBRUSH> (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
   wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
   wndclass.lpszClassName =windowClassName;
   ::RegisterClass(&wndclass);

   // Create our main, raw win32 API window
   // We create the window invisible (meaning that we do not provide WS_VISIBLE as the window style parameter), because making it visible and then
   // adding a HwndSource will make it flicker.
   HWND mainWindow = ::CreateWindow(
      windowClassName,
      windowTitle,
      0,
      CW_USEDEFAULT,
      CW_USEDEFAULT,
      windowWidth,
      windowHeight,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      hInstance,
      0);
   ::ShowWindow (mainWindow, nCmdShow);
   ::UpdateWindow( mainWindow );

//ocx

    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *PFonc)(IUnknown*, HWND,IUnknown**);   
    HINSTANCE hDLL2 = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("atl.dll"));   
    if (!hDLL2) 
      return 1;   
    //PAttachControl AtlAxAttachControl = (PAttachControl) GetProcAddress(hDLL2, (LPCSTR)"AtlAxAttachControl");
    PFonc AtlAxAttachControl = (PFonc) ::GetProcAddress(hDLL2,"AtlAxAttachControl");
    CLSID clsid = GetClsid();
    IID DIID__DLiveX = GetDIID__DLiveX();
    RECT rect;
    ::GetClientRect(mainWindow,&rect);

    container = ::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT",L"",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,rect.right,rect.bottom,mainWindow,0,hInstance,0);

    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(0);


IWebBrowser2 *pIwb;
IUnknown*       unkn;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WebBrowser,0,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IWebBrowser2,(void**)&pIwb);
hr = AtlAxAttachControl(pIwb,container,0);
     if(FAILED(hr)){
         MessageBox(0, L"FAILED(AtlAxAttachControl(pitd, container, NULL))", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
     pIwb->GoHome();
     pIwb->Navigate2((VARIANT*)L"www.google.com",0,0,0,0);

   // Start message processing
   ::MSG message;
   while (::GetMessageA(&message, 0, 0, 0)) {
      switch (message.message) {
      case WM_QUIT:
         break;
      default:
         ::TranslateMessage(& message);
         ::DispatchMessage(& message);
         break;
      }
   }
   CoUninitialize();
   FreeLibrary(hDLL2);
   return 0;
}
```

but the when i execute my programme i got two window, one my originale empty and the Activex in another wind,

Thanks.

Comment: here you go buddy: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218442

Answer (score 4):

I have made small changes and it compiles and shows only one window with an ActiveX included:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <oledlg.h>

using namespace std;

// Constants

namespace {
   TCHAR * windowClassName = TEXT("win32host");
   TCHAR * windowTitle     = TEXT("Win32 interface");
   int          windowWidth     = 600;
   int          windowHeight    = 600;
}

    HWND container;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT messg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch(messg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
        // Redimensionnement du conteneur quand la taille de la fenêtre change:
        MoveWindow(container,0,0,LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam),1);
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
        // Détruire la fenêtre principale:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        // Envoyer le message de sortie du programme:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        break;
        default:
        //Retour:
        return( DefWindowProc( hWnd, messg, wParam, lParam ) );
    }
    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
   HINSTANCE hInstance,
   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
   int nCmdShow)
{

   // Register our Window class
   WNDCLASS wndclass;
   wndclass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
   wndclass.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc;
   wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
   wndclass.hIcon = NULL;
   wndclass.hCursor = NULL;
   wndclass.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast <HBRUSH> (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
   wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
   wndclass.lpszClassName =windowClassName;
   ::RegisterClass(&wndclass);

   // Create our main, raw win32 API window
   // We create the window invisible (meaning that we do not provide WS_VISIBLE as the window style parameter), because making it visible and then
   // adding a HwndSource will make it flicker.
   HWND mainWindow = ::CreateWindow(
      windowClassName,
      windowTitle,
      0,
      CW_USEDEFAULT,
      CW_USEDEFAULT,
      windowWidth,
      windowHeight,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      hInstance,
      0);
   ::ShowWindow (mainWindow, nCmdShow);
   ::UpdateWindow( mainWindow );

    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *PFonc)(IUnknown*, HWND,IUnknown**);   
    HINSTANCE hDLL2 = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("atl.dll"));   
    if (!hDLL2) 
      return 1;   

    PFonc AtlAxAttachControl = (PFonc) ::GetProcAddress(hDLL2,"AtlAxAttachControl");

    RECT rect;
    ::GetClientRect(mainWindow,&rect);

    container = ::CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 
        L"EDIT",
        L"",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        0,
        0,
        rect.right,
        rect.bottom,
        mainWindow,
        0,
        hInstance,
        0);

    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(0);


    IWebBrowser2 *pIwb;
    hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WebBrowser,0,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IWebBrowser2,(void**)&pIwb);
    hr = AtlAxAttachControl(pIwb,container,0);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
         MessageBox(0, L"FAILED(AtlAxAttachControl(pitd, container, NULL))", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
     pIwb->GoHome();
     pIwb->Navigate2((VARIANT*)L"www.google.com",0,0,0,0);

   // Start message processing
   ::MSG message;
   while (::GetMessageA(&message, 0, 0, 0))
   {
      switch (message.message) {
      case WM_QUIT:
         break;
      default:
         ::TranslateMessage(& message);
         ::DispatchMessage(& message);
         break;
      }
   }

   CoUninitialize();
   FreeLibrary(hDLL2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh ok... i guess it could be a version issue then.  not sure.  i tried it and nothing showed up.  i mean the one window shows up, but it's not browsing..  there's a ton of different versions of ie browser activex objects.. who knows.

Comment: or microsoft hates me.. who knows.  same code i did awhile ago used to work.  anyway, just curious...

Comment: thanks for reply but i don't see where are the changes that you are maked ;)

Comment: Your original code has not compiled so I have adapted it a little bit removing some things like #include "test.h", using namespace System and so long ... Basically I just changed the offset of child window (you had 100, 100 and I changed it to 0, 0). But the message is - you code works good on my computer and shows what it should to show ... The poit was to use in :CreateWindowEx the mainWindow as a parent what you have already done.

Comment: can you guys post the specs of your pc?  windows version?  IE version?  i think that may be the culprit.

Comment: I see ... So I run Windows 8 64 Bit on DELL Intel Xeon / VS 2012 / IE 10

Comment: well i run win7, ie 9... so that's probably it.  i'll try on the win8 machine when i have a chance

Comment: No need, I can try it in Win7, just rebooting ... Hold the line

Comment: probably from the "home" page.  hm.. not sure why mine doesn't load then.

Answer (score 2):

I test out duDE's code and it works except it did not browse to the requested URL.

I am quite surprise that ocx can be used in win32 without ATL/MFC so easily in this way, but it actually works.

I think the failure to browse is because:

```
     pIwb->Navigate2((VARIANT*)L"www.google.com",0,0,0,0);
```

Change it to:

```
// create variant for url
VARIANT varUrl;
// init variant
VariantInit(&varUrl);
varUrl.vt = VT_BSTR;
varUrl.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"www.google.com");
// browse to url
hr = pIwb->Navigate2((VARIANT*)&varUrl,0,0,0,0);
// release variant
VariantClear(&varUrl);
```

Comment: ah, good call.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094(v=vs.85).aspx it's activex.  input is variant.  otherwise, it would have trouble with dynamic type binding for languages like visual basic.  that's the issue.  good eye.  +1.

Comment: in fact, this explains why he gets bing's page.  in his windows 8 machine, he probably has home set to google.  so that he gets google is a coincidence!  now everything makes sense again, and microsoft doesn't hate me... thank you!

Comment: @thang - Thanks for the info, I think your code should work too, with this modification.